# How to make traffic time contour map in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, contour

I want to make travel time contour map which shows the area people can go from an origin (e.g. downtown, airport) within certain time interval. I have a roadway linear shapefile with the information of travel time and some example maps found online, but lack of the idea how to make the map. Thanks for your help! [image]

[image]

Comment: What level of license do you have - specifically, do you have access to Network Analyst? If so this is a Service Area analysis.

Comment: This can be done for US & Canada (for free) http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/gmaps/samples/geoprocessor/gp_servicearea.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using ESRI you need [Network Analyst](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_Network_Analyst/004700000001000000/) extension in order to build a network dataset, but with Spatial Analyst you should be able to use the [Cost Distance tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000018000000.htm) to produce something along the lines of your desired "contours."